# Development Mode requires the GWT Developer Plugin

Tags: javascript, gwt

My project using GWT. I haved installed GWT plugin for my Chrome Browser before . I am using the newest version of chrome .When run the project,  Chrome browser alway announce

> Development Mode requires the GWT Developer Plugin

I have attached the image bellow

[image]

But when I click to the link. Chrome browser go to page of plugin in the Chrome web Store. But it announce me that my chrome browser haved installed this plugin. I have attached the screenshot bellow
[image]

How can I make GWT plugin work with my project ?
Thank for any help

Comment: what version of chrome you are using?

Comment: @Mohammed Version 42.0.2311.90 m. My Chrome is newest

Comment: Either downgrade the google chrome version to older or use SDM

Comment: Duplicate Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750514/gwt-plugin-doesnt-work-in-chrome-42

Comment: I was facing same problem. It got solved using GWT Super Dev Mode.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From GWT Website  ,http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_6_1

- GWT Development Mode will no longer be available for Chrome sometime in 2014, so we improved alternate ways of debugging. There are improvements to Super Dev Mode, asserts, console logging, and error messages.

This is because of newer chrome version.Use Super Dev Mode

Other Solution is you can enable NPAPI  which was disable in chrome 42 version follow the below steps

1.Open New Tab and Enter `chrome://flags/#enable-npapi`

2.Enable this `Enable NPAPI Mac, Windows`

3.Then bottom of the page click "Relunch" button.

Comment: which version of chrome u r using?

Comment: as work around you can use Firefox 24.0 - it works completely fine with GWT plugin , it also has good developer tool in it , just make sure not to update the Firefox 24.0 - to further versions available

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue this morning.

Switching to super dev mode:

select your project in the Project Explorer -> Debug as -> Web Application(Super Dev Mode)

Console will say: 
The code server is ready.
Next, visit: http://127.0.0.1:9876/

Do so and follow instructions there.

Answer (score 4):

Quick recap: Firefox nuked APIs that DevMode needed in 27.0, more than a year ago; Chrome announced approximately at the same time that they were deprecating NPAPI, that DevMode needs. They first made it impossible to update extensions containing NPAPI plugins in the Chrome Web Store a year ago, then they removed NPAPI support on Linux, and now they've just disabled NPAPI in Chrome 42, and will remove support entirely in 45, to be released in September.

"Classic" DevMode is deprecated for nearly 1½ year now; it really is time to move to SuperDevMode!

Comment: Hi thomas,What is final version of chrome which will support "Classic" DevMode?

Comment: I consider it unsupported already. I totally unmaintained for more than a year, with all efforts put on improving SuperDevMode. Now is the time to switch if you haven't already. From what I read here and there, Chrome 44 on Windows and OSX should still support it (behind a flag to re-enable NPAPI).

Answer (score 3):

It's very likely that you are following word for word the instructions from Google at this link.

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started

The instructions are out of date, and not valid for current versions of chrome.

Instead of selecting the option

**Debug As > Web Application**

use the option

**Debug As > Web Application (GWT Super Dev Mode)**

Google has "given up" on keeping their documentation up to date.   I can only imagine how difficult it must be to ignore so many complaints.

Answer (score 2):

From GWT Website  ,http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_6_1

- GWT Development Mode will no longer be available for Chrome sometime in 2014, so we improved alternate ways of debugging. There are improvements to Super Dev Mode, asserts, console logging, and error messages.

This is because of newer chrome version.Use Super Dev Mode

Answer (score 2):

NPAPI can be re-enabled in Chrome but it is going away.

Super dev mode supposed to be the way forward but I prefer the classic dev mode.

I'm using Windows. I installed a version of Chromium to stop this being a problem for me. The version I found to be the last of the 41 series was build 310958 which can be obtained here:

https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Win/310958/

You need to download the mini_installer.exe file. This version of Chromium will never update itself.

I recommend also that you make a copy of the GWT Developer Plugin that you can install without using Google's store because I believe it will be removed soon. I don't know how to do that, but one member of my team claims to have done it.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is there, as **Google has now completely discarded NPAPI which is required by GWT developer plugin** which can been seen here:http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html

Google now provides "Super Dev Mode" which does not require NPAPI.

For utilizing that you can check this blog: https://www.sencha.com/blog/getting-started-with-gwt-super-dev-mode/

Answer (score 2):

[Firefox Portable 26.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/Mozilla%20Firefox,%20Portable%20Ed./Mozilla%20Firefox,%20Portable%20Edition%2026.0/) supports the GWT Developer Plugin needed to work with Classic Dev Mode.  You can install that along side an up-to-date browser.

For some reason, Super Dev Mode still does not work with some projects.  This workaround has worked best for our team.

Answer (score 2):

To get it working on Mac: download [this](https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-snapshots/o/Mac%2F281482%2Fchrome-mac.zip?generation=1409087432937000&alt=media) version (Version 38.0.2084.0 (281482)) and install the plugin from the Chrome Web Store.

Answer (score 1):

I did the same thing as suggested by davtom and it worked. I download the chrome-win32.zip file from https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Win/310958/ . I unzipped the files in a temp folder and run chrome.exe from there.

Thanks Davtom. This problem was driving me nuts for the past 3 hours. I rebooted, installed a different JDK, uninstalled and reinstalled the plugin but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

To overcome this problem, Install very old version of chrome [version 10](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/download/google-chrome-10-0-648-127-1) and run the app in super-dev mode. It would run as it should. There is no requirement to install GWT plugin for this version of chrome.