# Gwt plugin doesn't work in Chrome 42

Tags: windows, google-chrome, gwt

The new version of chrome (42) doesn't support **gwt plugin** on windows 8.1 even I change the compatibility mode to Windows 7 I still  get prompted to download the plugin again. I've tried removing it and re-installing but I still get this message.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From GWT Website ,http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_6_1

GWT Development Mode will no longer be available for Chrome sometime in 2014, so we improved alternate ways of debugging. There are improvements to Super Dev Mode, asserts, console logging, and error messages.
This is because of newer chrome version.Use Super Dev Mode

Other Solution is you can enable NPAPI which was disable in chrome 42 version follow the below steps

1.Open New Tab and Enter chrome://flags/#enable-npapi

2.Enable this Enable NPAPI Mac, Windows

3.Then bottom of the page click "Relunch" button.

Which is i already explained here [Development Mode requires the GWT Developer Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29743214/development-mode-requires-the-gwt-developer-plugin/29747647#29747647)

Comment: Thanks for your help but this solution will be available just until April 2015 :/

Comment: yup..Might be that option will disappear in Chrome version 45..this is work around..

Comment: NPAPI  is scheduled to be removed from Chrome in September 2015.  Google now provides "Super Dev Mode" which does not require NPAPI.

Comment: Yup fishjd..you are correct..but still if anybody wants to use Classic Dev mode to be run in chrome 42,they can go with this work around

Comment: as work around you can use Firefox 24.0 - it works completely fine with GWT plugin , it also has good developer tool in it , just make sure not to update the Firefox 24.0 - to further versions available