# gwt 2.7 code is not complying is superDevMode

Tags: gwt

I'm using gwt 2.7 with eclipse LUNA on WIndows 8.
Till now i used the classic development mode and it worked perfectly with Chrome. Somehow without doing anything I cannot run it anymore and every time i open the link in Chrome i'm getting a message to install the GWT plugin although its installed.
I tried switching to SuperDevMode. When i start the server everything looks good. I see in the console that the project is compiling and that the server is running. From the console: 
*The code server is ready at http://127.0.0.1:9876/
Code server started in 3903 ms
waited 1043 ms for code server to finish*

When I open the URL in the client, I see a message in the browser that the project is compiling and eventually it failed.
In the console:

```
 [ERROR] Compiler returned false
  [WARN] recompile failed
  job's progress set to ERROR: com.jobsin.JobMarker_1_0
  [WARN] continuing to serve previous version
```

RESPONSE /recompile/jobmarker  200 handled=true
Enabled read interest SCEP@3185c77d{l(/127.0.0.1:49686)<->r(/127.0.0.1:9876),s=1,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@45ebf8f1,g=HttpGenerator{s=4,h=0,b=0,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=312,c=0},r=2}
filled 0/0

When i look on the compiler output i dont see any error message

What am I doing wrong?

Ofer

Comment: Re: the plugin in Chrome, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/29743214/116472; wrt the failed recompilation, do you really have no more precise error in the console? Have you tried increasing the log level? (e.g. `-logLevel TRACE` or `-logLevel DEBUG`)

Comment: I have increased the log level to All and found some compilation errors that the gwt compiler pass. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

in GWT 2.7, superdevmode is now the default. Here are the release notes: http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_7_0
It looks like you have to explicitely set the -noSuperDevMode flag to run dev mode.